# How to assign Object from MainContext to Object in ChildContext using a Picker in CoreData and Swift(UI)?

Tags: swift, core-data

**Context**

I am currently working with `CoreData` and encountered a problem. I have an `FormViewModel` that uses a `ChildContext` of the `MainContext` as a scratchpad for changes before they are saved.

My problem is, that the new `Object` has a relationship to another `Entity`. These `Objects` are already present. However, the app crashes every time I try to assign one of these `Objects` (only present in the `MainContext`) to the new `Object` in the `ChildContext` using a `SwiftUI` `Picker`.

> **Error:** Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'profileCD' between objects in different contexts

---

**Question**

- How can I solve this problem? Is it possible to copy the entire `MainContext` over to `ChildContext` to have access to all `Objects` or do I need to manually copy the selected `Object` over?

Comment: You need to get the equivalent object within the context you're using. Here, your picker is using MainContext while your created object is in child one. You can fetch (with a FetchRequest) the item within child context (matching its unique id, name, etc or whatever identifies it), or try with `let objectInChildContext = child.object(with:objectFromMainContext.objectId)`

Comment: @Larme thanks for your answer! Is the `ChildContext` on creation a copy of the `MainContext` meaning all `Objects` are copied? Or is it empty? When the first is true, how can I fetch from the `ChildContext` using a `FetchRequest`. When the second is true, how do I copy the selected `Object` over to the `ChildContext`. A small code example would be lovely, I would also grant you a bounty once available.

Comment: The solution is already in the comment, if you use `object(with:)` or the one I prefer, `existingObject(with:)`, on the child context the object will be loaded into the context and returned so you can use it.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks a lot for your answer. What I tried is to just update the `.environment(\.managedObjectContext)` of the `Picker` to the `ChildContext`. The `Picker` presents all options and it does not throw an error once you assign one to the new `Item` inside `ChildContext`. Is this fine or is there any problem I am overseeing?

Comment: I thought you are using the generic code in the [linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P8rqjs_CNsk) in your previous question. The solution is brilliant. There is a method `copyToChildContext`. Call it on each object which is going to be used in the child context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem?

A given managed object is only valid within its context, so you can't associate two objects from different contexts. The error you're getting more or less tells you the solution: if you want to associate two objects, they both need to exist in the same managed object context.

> Is it possible to copy the entire MainContext over to ChildContext to have access to all Objects or do I need to manually copy the selected Object over?

You already have access to all the objects in MainContext because MainContext is the store for ChildContext. However, if you fetch an object in MainContext, that reference isn't something you can use in ChildContext -- you need to fetch the object you want in ChildContext.

One way you can eliminate your error is to use managed object ID's. Let's say you have an object from MainContext in a variable called `person`, and you want to set that object as the `owner` of the new `car` object that you just created in ChildContext. You could perhaps do something like this:

```
car.owner = childContext.existingObject(with:person.objectID)
```

`existingObject(with:)` returns the managed object with the given ID if it already exists in the context (ChildContext in this case), or else fetches it from the store (MainContext in this case) if it doesn't. The result is that you get an object in ChildContext that you can associate with other objects in that context.